# React canvas with ref omitting calling ref.current and ctx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, ref

Is it possible to omit to call

```
const canvas = canvasRef.current;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

each time I want to refer to canvas DOM node in a function or useEffect hook?

```
const drawCanvas = () => {
  const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const x = canvas.width;
    const y = canvas.height;
    setPosition({ x, y });
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot set the current ref node to a variable.

If you have to implement the same logic in different components, you could create your own hook:

```js
const useCanvas = (callback) => {
  const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    callback([canvas, ctx]);
  }, []);

  return canvasRef;
}

const Canvas = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState({});
  const canvasRef = useCanvas(([canvas, ctx]) => {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const x = canvas.width;
    const y = canvas.height;
    setPosition({ x, y });
  });

  return (<canvas ref={canvasRef} />);
};
```

A few remarks:

- I renamed your `drawCanvas` function to `Canvas` - a more standard way to name your React function components
- The above custom hook is suited for a simple use case where it runs only once after the initial render. Otherwise, you could run into a problem with this approach (see here for more details: https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780)